# Is there any point-set definition of simple connectedness?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

The definition of path-connectedness refers to the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$. (More precisely, the interval $[0,1]$) On the other hand, connectedness is defined "purely" in terms of points and sets, and does not refer to $\mathbb{R}$.

The definition of simple connectedness also heavily depends on the interval $[0,1]$, or $S^1$.
So here's my question:
Is there any notion which is very similar to the usual simple connectedness, but defined "purely" in terms of points and sets? If there is one, is this useful?

Comment: Would "an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected if both it and its complement are connected in the Riemann sphere" meet your criteria?  If not, what's missing

Comment: I want a definition that applies to arbitrary topological spaces. For open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, I think the one you said is a good one.

Comment: It's a valid question, I think. A metric refers to $\mathbb{R}$ as well, but metrisability can be given a pure (equivalent) definition, so maybe here it is possible too. I have never heard of one, though.

Comment: If you accept the notion of homotopy groups for  simplicial complexs (which is, in principle, purely combinatorial) as not requiring the concept of real numbers then one can give such a definition not just for simple connectivity but for homotopy groups as well. This is done via Chech homotopy groups which are based on open coverings and their nerves (simplicial complexes) and then taking an inverse limit of homotopy groups of the latter. Details though are quite nasty.

Comment: @studiosus Not to mention, the two answers are only known to agree for spaces that are very nice, say locally paracompact and locally contractible.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, of course, similarly to the fact that  connectivity is not the same as path connectivity in general. Arguably, Chech definition is much better suited for pathalogical spaces than for the nice ones (like CW complexes).

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended version of my comment. There are two competing homotopy theories which address the question that you asked, these are Čech and Steenrod (or Steenrod-Sitnikov) homotopy theories. You can find a detailed discussion of these for instance [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Edavide/Cech_and_Steenrod_Homotopy_Theories_with_Applications_to_Geometric_Topology.pdf). However, if you are just learning general topology and algebraic topology, both theories will be very hard to swallow. A slightly more elementary theory is the one of Čech homology (or cohomology) groups, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_cohomology). The idea is to "approximate" the given (pointed in the homotopy case) topological space $X$ with a sequence of simplicial complexes $C_i$, which are nerves of certain open covers of $X$. For each $C_i$ one can define (co)homology and homotopy groups purely combinatorially. (These groups form a natural inverse system and one then can take the inverse limit. This is Čech's construction. The one due to Steenrod is even more complex.) You might be familiar with this construction in the context of homology groups. Note that the notion of a simplicial complex, while motivated by the geometric notion of a simplex (which does require real numbers) is in fact purely combinatorial, like the more elementary notion of a graph. Hence, its (co)homology groups can be defined combinatorially. For instance, to define the combinatorial $\pi_1$, you can think of the elements of this group as equivalence classes of based edge-paths. This equivalence is generated via elementary homotopy of such edge-paths, where an edge of a 2-simplex $s$ is replaced by the concatenation of the two other edges of $s$ (and vice-versa).

In the case of "nice" topological spaces (like CW-complexes), the homotopy and (co)homology groups thus defined are isomorphic to the ones defined via maps of intervals/cubes/spheres and singular/cellular simplices.

Needless to say, I suggest you first get comfortable with the standard algebraic topology (e.g. in Hatcher's book) before trying to deal with anything like Čech homotopy groups.

Answer (score 1):

For many spaces, such as CW complexes, path connectedness is equivalent to connectedness. Also, the loop space of a CW complex has the homotopy type of a CW complex (this theorem of Milnor may need some extra assumptions, like finiteness, I don't know the exact statement). Thus, for CW complexes at least, simple connectedness can be defined in terms of connectedness alone : a CW complex is simply connected *iff* it is connected and its loop space (at some (any) point) is connected. The same then holds for higher connectivity (unless there is some finiteness hypothesis in Milnor's theorem.)

Comment: If we're going to dismiss the usual definition of simple connectedness because it involves heavily the topology of $[0,1]$, I don't think an answer involving $\Omega X$ would work.

Comment: @nik I understand your point, but it's the best I could think of, and in the very least it shows that simple connectedness _can_ be reduced to connectedness of $X$ and an auxiliary space.

Comment: CW complex itself requires $\mathbb{R}$, in fact even more: $n$-dimensional balls and their boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of covering is purely "points and sets": a map $\pi:Y\to X$ is a covering if it is surjective and every $p\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U\subset X$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of copies of $U$. Now, let $X$ be a connected topological space. You can say that $X$ is simply connected if it has no nontrivial connected covering. This coincides with the usual notion of simply connectedness when $X$ is reasonable.